# WhatsApp business Cloud API - send calendar events

Tags: whatsapp-cloud-api

Using WhatsApp's Business Cloud API, how can I send a reminder message with a calendar event that my customers can easily add to their device calendar? I didn't find any way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific type for calendar invite in WhatsApp Business API.

I would suggest you can prepare that logic/functionality in your web page, or any API that will export/download the calendar file and add it to the user's calendar.

You can put a URL button on the WhatsApp template and just add your Web Page/API URL to that button, so the user can click and follow your instructions.